# Using Scanner to print lines from file

Tags: python, loops, command-prompt

Im trying to read a file using a scanner then have my program print the first line of the file then looping over each other individual line throughout the file and printing them as well. This issue is I cant even get it to print a single line from the first file. And I'm not receiving an error so I cant figure out the issue

```
import sys
import scanner

def main():
    log1 = (sys.argv[1])
    log2 = (sys.argv[2])

    def readRecords(s):
        s = Scanner("log1")
        print (log1)

main()
```

Comment: You are never calling your readRecords inner function. Perhaps you could elaborate on what scanner is and how Scanner objects should behave?

Comment: What is scanner and where does it come from? As @Ben points out, you define readRecords(s) as a function inside of main, but then never call it.

Comment: A scanner is a reading subsystem that allows you to read whitespace-delimited tokens from a file.

Answer (score 1):

I will go out on a limb here and suggest something like:

```
import sys
import scanner

def readRecords(log):
    s = scanner.Scanner(log)
    print s.SomeAttribute

def main():
    log1 = (sys.argv[1])
    log2 = (sys.argv[2])

    readRecords(log1)
    readRecords(log2)

main()
```

Your original code has numerous problems though, least of which you are never calling your readRecords function. You are also never defining/importing `Scanner`, and you are doing nothing with the `s` variable that you are assigning to (unless merely creating a Scanner object has the desired side-effect).